# Add a single field to model using raw SQL

Tags: typo3, datamapper, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I'm developing an extension for TYPO3 CMS 8.7.8. I'm using `query->statement()` to select all fields from a single table, plus 1 field from another table. I get a `QueryResult` with the proper models and I would like to have that 1 extra field added to them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do SQL queries with the `->statement(...)` method and in that, use normal `JOIN` commands

From the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html)

```
$result = $query->statement('SELECT * FROM tx_sjroffers_domain_model_offer
WHERE title LIKE ? AND organization IN ?', array('%climbing%', array(33,47)));
```

So you can do JOINs on whatever table you want to (also code from the documentation)

```
LEFT JOIN tx_blogexample_person
ON tx_blogexample_post.author = tx_blogexample_person.uid
```

But you will end up with the raw data from the mysql query. If you want to transform it into a object, use the [Property Mapper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/4-Property-mapping.html#how-to-use-property-mapper)

Comment: My question is aimed at how to get the extra field onto the Model. I've managed to change the Model to accommodate the extra field and added TCA configuration for the field. Now everything works fine.

Comment: @StephanRodemeier Then you could like into creating your own TypeConverter and have that extra field being added to your returned model. Look how PersistentObjectConverter and similar does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` in your sql `statments` like below.

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$sql = 'SELECT single.*,another.field_anme AS fields_name
        FROM
           tx_single_table_name single
        JOIN
           tx_another_table_name another
        ON
           single.fields = another.uid
        WHERE
           O.deleted = 0
        AND O.hidden=0
        AND O.uid=' . $orderId;
return $query->statement($sql)->execute();
```